# how to update a recyclerView from a room database with live data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, viewmodel, android-livedata

I am building a news app that fetches data from a rest server using retrofit. I use MVVM architecture. the user clicks a category and the recyclerview should be updated with lists from a room database with the specific category. But somehow I am stuck with the same list of news from the same category! I suspect these tow lines of code are causing the problem

```
private var defaultCategory: String = "general"

    var articles: LiveData<List<NewsArticleForDatabase>> =
        database.articleDao().getCategoryArticles(defaultCategory)
```

I change the `defaultCategory` variable whith the one the user have chosen and invoke the `refreshNewsArticles()` method, the database is updated internally but the `articles` variable still hold the lists from the first declaration `private var defaultCategory: String = "general"`
is there anyway to solve this problem, I appreciate any help

```
const val TAG = "NewsViewModel"

class NewsViewModel(application: Application) : ViewModel() {
    private val newsRepository = NewsRepository(ArticleDatabase.getDatabase(application))

    private val _newsArticle = MutableLiveData<NewsArticleForDatabase>()
    val newsArticle: LiveData<NewsArticleForDatabase> = _newsArticle

    private val _newsArticles = newsRepository.articles
    val newsArticles: LiveData<List<NewsArticleForDatabase>> = _newsArticles

    val BUSINESS = "business"
    val ENTERTAINMENT = "entertainment"
    val GENERAL = "general"
    val HEALTH = "health"
    val SCIENCE = "science"
    val SPORTS = "sports"
    val TECHNOLOGYY = "technology"

    init {
        refreshDataFromRepository(GENERAL)
    }

    private fun refreshDataFromRepository(category: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            newsRepository.refreshNewsArticles(category)
            Log.d(TAG,"articles arry size  := ${newsArticles.value!!.size}")
            Log.d(TAG,"articles category := ${newsArticles.value!![10].category}")
        }
    }

    fun onButtonPressedGetNews(category: String) {
        refreshDataFromRepository(category)
    }

    fun onArticleClicked(article: NewsArticleForDatabase) {
        _newsArticle.value = article
    }
}


private const val TAG = "NewsRepository"

class NewsRepository(private val database: ArticleDatabase) {

    private val COUNTRY: String = "us"
    private var defaultCategory: String = "general"

    var articles: LiveData<List<NewsArticleForDatabase>> =
        database.articleDao().getCategoryArticles(defaultCategory)

    suspend fun refreshNewsArticles(category: String) {
        defaultCategory = category
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val articleList: NewsApiResponse
            try {
                articleList = NewsApi.retrofitService.getHeadlines(api_key, category, COUNTRY)
                Log.d(TAG, "retrofit articles list:- ${articleList.articles.size}")
                var articleForDao: NewsArticleForDatabase
                for (article in articleList.articles) {
                    articleForDao = getNewsArticleForDatabase(
                        article.source,
                        article.author,
                        article.title,
                        article.description,
                        article.url,
                        article.urlToImage,
                        article.publishedAt,
                        article.content,
                        category
                    )
                    database.articleDao().upsert(articleForDao)
                    Log.d(TAG,"database size :- ${database.articleDao().getAllArticles().value!!.size} ")
                }
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString())
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"default category is :- ${defaultCategory.toString()}")
    }

    private fun getNewsArticleForDatabase(
        source: Source?,
        author: String?,
        title: String,
        description: String?,
        url: String?,
        urlToImage: String?,
        publishedAt: String?,
        content: String?,
        category: String
    ): NewsArticleForDatabase {
        return NewsArticleForDatabase(
            source,
            author,
            title,
            description,
            url,
            urlToImage,
            publishedAt,
            content,
            category
        )
    }
}

@Dao
interface ArticleDao {

    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun upsert(articles:NewsArticleForDatabase)

    @Query ("select * from newsArticlesDatabase")
    fun getAllArticles(): LiveData<List<NewsArticleForDatabase>>

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(article: NewsArticleForDatabase)

    @Query ("select * from newsArticlesDatabase where category = :userCategory")
    fun getCategoryArticles(userCategory: String): LiveData<List<NewsArticleForDatabase>>
}



<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            ...
            app:listData="@{viewModel.newsArticles}"
            ... />
```

Comment: Create a  `category` MutableLiveData with initial value of `”general”`. Change `articles` to use `switchMap` on the `category`. When the user changes categories, update the `category` live data value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Tenfour04!

now my recylcer view works fine according to the user category.
you saved me hours of frustration.
I changed these lines in the NewsRepository class

```
...

    private var defaultCategory = MutableLiveData<String>("sports")
    
        var articles: LiveData<List<NewsArticleForDatabase>> = Transformations.switchMap(defaultCategory) {
            database.articleDao().getCategoryArticles(it)
        }
...
```

and added code line to update the `category` when the user clicks the category button in the UI

```
suspend fun refreshNewsArticles(category: String) {

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            ...
        }
        defaultCategory.value = category
    }
```

Note:? when I updated the category inside the coroutine  thread it gave me this error
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread`
I would be happy if someone explain why it didn't work, only in the main thread it will compile .